# Does spring LDAP requires initial username and password?

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I am trying to connect to Active Directory using Spring LDAP, but I don't have available information about the username and password.

**My question is:** Is there a way to connect using spring ldap without initial username and password, and only get these credentials from user at run time
I already tried to connect to ldap with java without initial credentials and it works fine, so is this available in spring as well?
Thanks in advance

Comment: which library do you actually use to access ldap? is it `org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core`?

Comment: yes, dependencies   
 `<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
 </dependency>
  
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
  <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>`

Comment: seems like no, because spring initializes connection to ldap at first connection

Comment: @Vladimir Shefer Thanks alot